# Django 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'count'

Tags: python, django

I am writing an application where users can add events and other users can add likes to them.
I'm stuck at the point where Django needs to sum up all likes for all posts.

Based on similar answers, I tried the code below for one event:

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='/oauth2/login')
def Events(request, *args):
    ...
    likes = EventModel.likes.count()
    return render(request, 'base/events.html', {..., 'likes': likes})
```

**models.py**

```
class EventModel(models.Model):
    ...
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='event_likes')
```

But when I refresh it returns an error

> 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'count'

How can I count all likes for all posts? I think it is too naive to execute loops and write them all in, for example, a dictionary.
[Here is how the site looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcCjw.png)
I am happy to provide more details regarding my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the count of *all* likes regardless of the `EventModel` instance, then you can access the `through` model (i.e. the intermediate model Django makes automatically for a `ManyToManyField` unless specified) and make a query on that:

```py
likes = EventModel.likes.through.objects.count()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I’ll mark I it as solved

Answer (score 2):

You need EventModel object instead of Model itself.

```
def Events(request, *args):
    event = EventModel.objects.get(pk=1)
    likes = event.likes.all().count()
```